# How to change keyboard language with command line on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I use <kbd>LShift</kbd> + <kbd>LAlt</kbd> to quick change language but Windows showing that annoing language popup and that thing have long delay which just killing me.. Sometimes it just dont want to close until I change language again.

What I want to do:

- Disable default Windows shortcut (<kbd>LShift</kbd> + <kbd>LAlt</kbd>) from *Advanced keyboard settings/Input language hot key*
- Download some app to add shortcut which will run the command
- Command* which will change the language via CMD, Powershell or idk.
- Rest easy tonight :)

*Command something like `changeLanguage --next` which will just change the language to the next one.

[STUPID POPUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDewD.png)

Note: [this solution dont work :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096875/programmatically-change-keyboard-layout)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096875/programmatically-change-keyboard-layout This should help.

Comment: @davidbaumann You think I cant Google my problem??, they give solution which writed in 2007.

Comment: Hah this is how you do it:
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.SendKeys('%+')

Comment: Please mark as 'answered' xD

Comment: @MMNandM yes its work but this just triggering shift alt combinations if i disable it from settings this will not work.